# How do I send a message with textbelt with user input using bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to send sms messages with a bash script using textbelt.

When I use `read varnumber` to save the number, textbelt only sends the first word in the message. Because there is a space in the message, the code ignores the rest of the message.

```
    echo What number would you like to message?
    read varnumber
    echo What would you like to say?
    read varmessage

    curl -X POST https://textbelt.com/text \
        --data-urlencode phone=$varnumber \
        --data-urlencode message=$varmessage \
        -d key=textbelt
```

Comment: Post the relevant part of your code as text in your question, not as screenshot. We can't do copy&paste from a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

General rule:

> Quote it if it can either be empty or contain spaces (or any whitespace really) or special characters (wildcards). Not quoting strings with spaces often leads to the shell breaking apart a single argument into many.

So putting the variables in your curl query in quotes, should solve the problem.

```
curl -X POST https://textbelt.com/text \
    --data-urlencode phone="$varnumber" \
    --data-urlencode message="$varmessage" \
    -d key=textbelt
```

Also, you may want to put your console output into quotes:

```
echo "Whatever you want to write here"
```

Or to combine output/input you could use `read -p`:

```
read -p "What is your phonenumber? " varnumber
```